# Pow en librería (leer desde Excel)

Tags: c++, dev-c++, visual-c++

He creado una función muy simple con POW, todo dentro de una librería (dll) dinámica que quiero usar desde Excel. En Excel puedo usar la función pero sea cuales sea los números que ingreso el resultado me da siempre 1. Sospecho que el dilema está en los códigos que uso para exportar/importar o en el Extern C, pero sinceramente no sé como arreglarlo. Tengo lo siguiente:

```
// xxxx.h - Contains declarations of our functions
#pragma once
 
#ifdef xxxx_EXPORTS
#define xxxx_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define xxxx_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
 
extern "C" xxxx_API double Mipotencia(double nBase, double nExponente);



// xxxx.cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "xxxx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
 
double WINAPI Mipotencia(double nBase, double nExponente)
{
    double media;
    media = pow(nBase, nExponente);
    return (media);
}
```

Y en xxxx.def:

```
LIBRARY xxxx
EXPORTS
      Mipotencia
```

Y en el VBA de Excel tengo lo siguiente:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function Mipotencia _
 Lib "D:\Ejemplos\VCpp\xxxx\x64\Debug\xxxx.dll" _
(ByRef nBase As Double, ByRef nExponente As Double) As Double
 
Sub Prueba()
MsgBox Mipotencia(8, 4)
End Sub
```

Espero se entienda y tenga solución. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

La función `Mipotencia` recibe dos parámetros **por valor**, mientras que la declaración que haces en `VBA` indicas que los parámetros serán **referencias**

```
(ByRef nBase As Double, ByRef nExponente As Double) As Double
 ~~~~~                  ~~~~~
```

Entiendo que la declaración correcta sería:

```
(ByVal nBase As Double, ByVal nExponente As Double) As Double
```

También sería buena idea crear un proyecto de C++ específico que importe esa DLL y realice algunos cálculos con ella. De esa forma puedes verificar que tu DLL funciona perfectamente sin tener que preocuparte por otras capas de software.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por el consejo pero en VBA el uso de ByVal y ByRef está relacionado a la forma en que se trata la variable e igual cambiando  eso sigue dando el mismo dilema.

Comment: @AbrahamValencia VB no ha inventado nada en cuanto al uso de referencias. Una referencia es una suerte de puntero. Si tu defines una variable como ByRef, la función recibirá un puntero a la variable original. Es decir, el uso de ByVal y ByRef no es tan irrelevante. Otra cosa es que haya otros problemas por resolver en tu proyecto

Comment: Hola nuevamente estimado, creo que quizás me expliqué mal, pero en todo caso para nada es mi intención darte la contra o similar ya que, como bien mencionas, sí creo igual que tú que hay otro dilema, no relacionado al VBA, en lo que he elaborado y no he podio encontrarlo. Muchas gracias igual.